# Xcode 6.1 crash on "Edit scheme"

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode6

Xcode 6.1 crashed when I tried to get to this screen: Edit scheme -> Run -> Options tab

Sample screenshot: http://meandmark.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/Xcode-5-Current-Working-Directory.png

**Now it crashes every time I go to "Edit Scheme..."**

I'v tried rebooting and even reinstalling Xcode.
When I reinstalled Xcode I was able to open "Edit scheme" window, but Options tab crashed it again.

Crash report:

```
Process:               Xcode [404]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               6.1 (6604)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-6604000000000000~2e)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [404]

Date/Time:             2014-11-05 15:54:10.508 +0100
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10 (14A389)
Report Version:        11

Time Awake Since Boot: 710 seconds

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
Sending _editActiveContextAction: to <IDESchemeToolbarController: 0x7fa2173e4940> from <NSMenuItem: 0x7fa217598500 Edit Scheme…>
ProductBuildVersion: 6A1052d
UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInvalidArgumentException): *** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil
UserInfo: (null)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to switch your Mac OS language settings to English (System Preferences -> Language & Region), add English in Preferred Languages and set it to Primary. It helped me, I had Czech as my Primary Language and Xcode crashed every time I tried to access Options in Edit Scheme window. Works in Xcode 8, hadn't tried it in previous versions.

Answer (score 5):

use command: defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode

Solved my issue :)

Comment: For others, this will reset all of your Xcode settings, but will also deactivate all plugins or any other things you could have done to your Xcode. A huge help! Thanks.