# Xcode 7.2 crash on "Edit scheme"

Tags: ios, xcode

XCode crashed when I opened the Options tab in Edit scheme > Run. When I launched XCode again, I wasn't able to open the Edit scheme dialog at all.

I tried the answer from [Xcode 6.1 crash on "Edit scheme"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26760118/xcode-6-1-crash-on-edit-scheme)

I launched the terminal and executed the "defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode" command. After that, I was able to open the Edit scheme dialog, however XCode crashed again when I tried opening the Options tab.

Comment: Just to be sure, you already tried restarting your computer?

Comment: @NicolasMiari yes, I did, I even tried running the command and then restarting the computer, neither of which helped.

Comment: Just added [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39676780/4746398) my solution. Works perfectly in Xcode 8.